# Gmail style autocomplete picker for WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml, user-interface

I'm looking for a WPF control that looks and functions like gmail address bar. Essentially, i want a textbox based multi select picker with autocomplete. I tried searching around, and I couldn't find any. Is there something readily available?

Comment: do you find free component or paid as well?

Comment: I couldn't find free or paid ones. The only ones available are from sharepoint and active directory, but they seem to be tied to them. In the worst case, I might have to write my own.I'm looking for free one preferably.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although it is paid component, check out Telerik [RadAutoCompleteBox](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/wpf/controls/radautocompletebox/overview) component.

The screenshot is taken from official WPF demo application. You can download demo application at here: http://demos.telerik.com/wpf/

[image]